# How do I get the value of datetime picker in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, datetimepicker, react-native-datetimepicker

I am getting an object and I have no idea how to get the date from the datetime picker, this is my code basically:

```
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';

const [date,setDate] = React.useState(new Date())
const [today] = React.useState(new Date())

<DateTimePicker
    mode='date'
    // format="YYYY-MM-DD"
    value={today}
    display={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'spinner' : 'default'}
    // dateFormat="day month year"
    onChange={(value) => setFecha(value.event)}
    minimumDate={today}
/>
```

When the values changes (onChange), I get:

> LOG  {"_dispatchInstances": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": undefined, "actualDuration": 1.4214559942483902, "actualStartTime": 37562183.920335, "alternate": null, "child": [Circular], "childLanes": 0, "deletions": null, "dependencies": null, "elementType": [Function Picker], "flags": 1048577, "index": 1, "key": null, "lanes": 0, "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": null, "mode": 2, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": null, "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0.1864589974284172, "sibling": null, "stateNode": null, "subtreeFlags": 0, "tag": 0, "treeBaseDuration": 0.1898289993405342, "type": [Function Picker], "updateQueue": null}, "_debugSource": undefined, "actualDuration": 1.233424998819828, "actualStartTime": 37562184.10846, "alternate": null, "child": null, "childLanes": 0, "deletions": null, "dependencies": null, "elementType": "RNDateTimePicker", "flags": 0, "index": 0, "key": null, "lanes": 0, "memoizedProps": {"accentColor": undefined, "date": 1673489495509, "displayIOS": "spinner", "enabled": true, "locale": undefined, "maximumDate": undefined, "minimumDate": 1673489495509, "minuteInterval": undefined, "mode": "date", "onChange": [Function _onChange], "onPickerDismiss": [Function onDismiss], "onResponderTerminationRequest": [Function onResponderTerminationRequest], "onStartShouldSetResponder": [Function onStartShouldSetResponder], "style": undefined, "testID": undefined, "textColor": undefined, "themeVariant": undefined, "timeZoneOffsetInMinutes": undefined}, "memoizedState": null, "mode": 2, "pendingProps": {"accentColor": undefined, "date": 1673489495509, "displayIOS": "spinner", "enabled": true, "locale": undefined, "maximumDate": undefined, "minimumDate": 1673489495509, "minuteInterval": undefined, "mode": "date", "onChange": [Function _onChange], "onPickerDismiss": [Function onDismiss], "onResponderTerminationRequest": [Function onResponderTerminationRequest], "onStartShouldSetResponder": [Function onStartShouldSetResponder], "style": undefined, "testID": undefined, "textColor": undefined, "themeVariant": undefined, "timeZoneOffsetInMinutes": undefined}, "ref": null, "return": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": undefined, "actualDuration": 1.4214559942483902, "actualStartTime": 37562183.920335, "alternate": null, "child": [Circular], "childLanes": 0, "deletions": null, "dependencies": null, "elementType": [Function Picker], "flags": 1048577, "index": 1, "key": null, "lanes": 0, "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": null, "mode": 2, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": null, "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0.1864589974284172, "sibling": null, "stateNode": null, "subtreeFlags": 0, "tag": 0, "treeBaseDuration": 0.1898289993405342, "type": [Function Picker], "updateQueue": null}, "selfBaseDuration": 0.0033700019121170044, "sibling": null, "stateNode": {"_children": [Array], "_internalFiberInstanceHandleDEV": [Circular], "_nativeTag": 15355, "viewConfig": [Object]}, "subtreeFlags": 0, "tag": 5, "treeBaseDuration": 0.0033700019121170044, "type": "RNDateTimePicker", "updateQueue": null}, "_dispatchListeners": [Function _onChange], "_targetInst": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": undefined, "actualDuration": 1.4214559942483902, "actualStartTime": 37562183.920335, "alternate": null, "child": [Circular], "childLanes": 0, "deletions": null, "dependencies": null, "elementType": [Function Picker], "flags": 1048577, "index": 1, "key": null, "lanes": 0, "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": null, "mode": 2, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": null, "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0.1864589974284172, "sibling": null, "stateNode": null, "subtreeFlags": 0, "tag": 0, "treeBaseDuration": 0.1898289993405342, "type": [Function Picker], "updateQueue": null}, "_debugSource": undefined, "actualDuration": 1.233424998819828, "actualStartTime": 37562184.10846, "alternate": null, "child": null, "childLanes": 0, "deletions": null, "dependencies": null, "elementType": "RNDateTimePicker", "flags": 0, "index": 0, "key": null, "lanes": 0, "memoizedProps": {"accentColor": undefined, "date": 1673489495509, "displayIOS": "spinner", "enabled": true, "locale": undefined, "maximumDate": undefined, "minimumDate": 1673489495509, "minuteInterval": undefined, "mode": "date", "onChange": [Function _onChange], "onPickerDismiss": [Function onDismiss], "onResponderTerminationRequest": [Function onResponderTerminationRequest], "onStartShouldSetResponder": [Function onStartShouldSetResponder], "style": undefined, "testID": undefined, "textColor": undefined, "themeVariant": undefined, "timeZoneOffsetInMinutes": undefined}, "memoizedState": null, "mode": 2, "pendingProps": {"accentColor": undefined, "date": 1673489495509, "displayIOS": "spinner", "enabled": true, "locale": undefined, "maximumDate": undefined, "minimumDate": 1673489495509, "minuteInterval": undefined, "mode": "date", "onChange": [Function _onChange], "onPickerDismiss": [Function onDismiss], "onResponderTerminationRequest": [Function onResponderTerminationRequest], "onStartShouldSetResponder": [Function onStartShouldSetResponder], "style": undefined, "testID": undefined, "textColor": undefined, "themeVariant": undefined, "timeZoneOffsetInMinutes": undefined}, "ref": null, "return": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": undefined, "actualDuration": 1.4214559942483902, "actualStartTime": 37562183.920335, "alternate": null, "child": [Circular], "childLanes": 0, "deletions": null, "dependencies": null, "elementType": [Function Picker], "flags": 1048577, "index": 1, "key": null, "lanes": 0, "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": null, "mode": 2, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": null, "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0.1864589974284172, "sibling": null, "stateNode": null, "subtreeFlags": 0, "tag": 0, "treeBaseDuration": 0.1898289993405342, "type": [Function Picker], "updateQueue": null}, "selfBaseDuration": 0.0033700019121170044, "sibling": null, "stateNode": {"_children": [Array], "_internalFiberInstanceHandleDEV": [Circular], "_nativeTag": 15355, "viewConfig": [Object]}, "subtreeFlags": 0, "tag": 5, "treeBaseDuration": 0.0033700019121170044, "type": "RNDateTimePicker", "updateQueue": null}, "bubbles": undefined, "cancelable": undefined, "currentTarget": {"_children": [], "_internalFiberInstanceHandleDEV": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": undefined, "actualDuration": 1.233424998819828, "actualStartTime": 37562184.10846, "alternate": null, "child": null, "childLanes": 0, "deletions": null, "dependencies": null, "elementType": "RNDateTimePicker", "flags": 0, "index": 0, "key": null, "lanes": 0, "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": null, "mode": 2, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": null, "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0.0033700019121170044, "sibling": null, "stateNode": [Circular], "subtreeFlags": 0, "tag": 5, "treeBaseDuration": 0.0033700019121170044, "type": "RNDateTimePicker", "updateQueue": null}, "_nativeTag": 15355, "viewConfig": {"Commands": [Object], "Constants": [Object], "Manager": "RNDateTimePickerManager", "NativeProps": [Object], "baseModuleName": "RCTView", "bubblingEventTypes": [Object], "directEventTypes": [Object], "uiViewClassName": "RNDateTimePicker", "validAttributes": [Object]}}, "defaultPrevented": undefined, "dispatchConfig": {"phasedRegistrationNames": {"bubbled": "onChange", "captured": "onChangeCapture"}}, "eventPhase": undefined, "isDefaultPrevented": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse], "isPropagationStopped": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse], "isTrusted": undefined, "nativeEvent": {"target": 15355, "timestamp": 1678587095000}, "target": {"_children": [], "_internalFiberInstanceHandleDEV": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": undefined, "actualDuration": 1.233424998819828, "actualStartTime": 37562184.10846, "alternate": null, "child": null, "childLanes": 0, "deletions": null, "dependencies": null, "elementType": "RNDateTimePicker", "flags": 0, "index": 0, "key": null, "lanes": 0, "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": null, "mode": 2, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": null, "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0.0033700019121170044, "sibling": null, "stateNode": [Circular], "subtreeFlags": 0, "tag": 5, "treeBaseDuration": 0.0033700019121170044, "type": "RNDateTimePicker", "updateQueue": null}, "_nativeTag": 15355, "viewConfig": {"Commands": [Object], "Constants": [Object], "Manager": "RNDateTimePickerManager", "NativeProps": [Object], "baseModuleName": "RCTView", "bubblingEventTypes": [Object], "directEventTypes": [Object], "uiViewClassName": "RNDateTimePicker", "validAttributes": [Object]}}, "timeStamp": 1673489773775, "type": "set"}

I try changing the format, but I am unable to get something like "YYYY-MM-DD" or something I can manage to set in my "date" variable using setDate and then utilize in others purposes of the app.

Any help will be very appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you have shown here is the Event object.

From [the documentation](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker#onchange-optional), "*It receives the event and the date as parameters.*" - You are most likely looking for the second parameter to retrieve the date.

```
onChange={(event, value) => setFecha(value)} // <-- value should contain the date
```